# Exclude a match if it contains a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Many similar questions like this already exist, but they do not solve my problem. Now, with that being said, suppose I have a sentence- "patient was moved to be admitted to observation" and I want to match only the portion "to - - - - observation" Now , if I have "for obs" / "for observations" inside the sentence "to - - - - observation" then I do not want to match it.

My regex looks like this:

```
(\bin\b|\bto\b|\badmit\b).{0,100}(observation\b|\bobserve\b|\bobs\b)
```

but when I use negative look ahead like (?!for) like this:

```
(\bin\b|\bto\b|\badmit\b).{0,100}(?!(for))(observation\b|\bobserve\b|\bobs\b)
```

it still matches everything. 
What I need the regex to accomplish is if it gets "to admit for observation/ to observe/ in observation" it will match. But if there is "to admit for observations/ for obs/ in observations" then it will not match.

Update: The following regex is pretty much giving the output that I wanted.

```
 ((\bin\b|\bto\b)(?!.*for.*(?:\bobs\b|observations\b)).{0,100}(observation\b|\bobserve\b|\bobs\b))|((observation\b|\bobserve\b|\bobs\b).{0,100}(\bstatus\b|\bplace\b|time\b))|(\b(status|place[d]?|placing|admit(?:ted)?|(?:ting)?|start|time|move[d]?)\b.{0,100}(observation\b))
```

Comment: Are you using a particular language other than regular expressions?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify with some sample input text and expected results. Also, add the tool/language tag.

Comment: I am using http://regexr.com/, I just need the plain regex. I have updated the question and attached screenshot. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest simply filtering the matches using a second regex and skipping those that match.

Comment: Tried like this: (?!(\bfor\b).{0,100})(?!(observations))((\bin\b|\bto\b).{0,100}(observation\b|\bobserve\b|\bobs\b))
which is giving me the same output

Comment: I agree with @WiktorStribiżew, your matching requirements are unclear to me from the question. Are you sure they are clear to you also? Also I would ask, is Regex really the best tool for this job??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the regex flavor, but if it supports look-behinds, try

```
\b(in|to|admit)\b.{0,100}(?<!for\s)\b(observation|observe|obs)\b
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QxSEBr/1).

What your negative look-ahead does is to check that none of the words `observation`, `observe`, `obs` start with `for`, which is pretty obvious that they don't ;)

**Edit**

OK, so it's JS. You could try something like:

```
\b(in|to|admit|was)\b.{0,100}(?!\bfor)...\s(observation|observe|obs)\b
```

It simply makes sure the characters prior to the key word isn't `for`. (It does however require there to be at least three characters before the word.)

[Example here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QxSEBr/3).

(I've freewheeled a bit there ;)

Comment: the regex flavor is javascript and it gives pattern error in js, but thanks for your contribution. I have updated the question too

Comment: Use an optional capturing group, and check if its undefined. If it is, grab the match, else, discard.

Comment: That is not the case I am going for, you are assuming that after "for" there is 3 characters and then the keywords, in my case there can be any number of characters before the keywords @ClasG

Comment: No, I'm not assuming there are three characters after for. The `...` is there to "eat" the characters that **aren't** `for` (which we've made sure with the negative look-ahead).

Comment: @ClasG if I test your regex against this "patient was moved to be admitted for \r observation" it matches, which is not supposed to

Comment: First - it would be much easier if you pasted the samples in the question. Then we don't have to re-type them to experiment. And - it would have been easier to determine if `\r` is a carriage return or the string literal consisting of a \ and an `r`. Which is it?

Comment: @ClasG I figured out what I wanted, you can check it out here: http://regexr.com/3epjq and thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may check with `(\bfor\s+)?` if there is `for` + space(s) before the `observation`, `observe`, etc. and if the `for` is matched, discard the match, else grab it:

```js
var regex = /\b(in|to|admit|was)\b.{0,100}?(\bfor\s+)?(observation|observe|obs)\b/g;
const str = "late case manager feels safest to admit for obs as pt lives ...\nw pt case manager wil to admist obs 1930 pt";
var m, res=[];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m[2] === undefined) { 
      res.push(m[0]); 
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: My approach is much cleaner. Aslo, easier to maintain and expand.

Comment: your solution matches almost everything that I don't want to match, you can see yourself just by pasting the regex in my given link.

Comment: @feather: No, it *extracts* what you need. You do not need to use a huge and unreadable regex when you have the JS power at hand.